# Creative CA0132 no sound

Tags: linux, fedora, audio, alsa

I'm trying to get my sound card of my gigabyte g1 gaming ga-z170x-gaming 7 working.

I've installed fedora 23, kernel 4.4.7-300.fc23.x86_64, there is no sound, however `hdajacksensetest -a` shows my speakers plug connected, if I connect the headphones the front jack is connected too.

Dmesg shows:

```
[    3.025556] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: failed to add i915 component master (-19)
[    3.035484] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for CA0132: line_outs=1 (0xb/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    3.035486] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.035487] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x10/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.035487] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    3.035488] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0xc/0x0
[    3.035489] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    3.035490] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x12
[    3.035490] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x11
[    3.184901] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input9
[    3.185184] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input10
[    3.185447] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input11
[    3.185910] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input12
[    3.593978] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D0: ca0132 DSP downloaded and running
[    3.790194] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
[    3.790360] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
[    3.790499] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
[    4.382906] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D0: ca0132 DSP downloaded and running
```

My alsa info script is available [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=a9a42ea830f8bae48d2855c655ef52ccdebdcad4)

alsamixer shows everything turned on and unmuted

UPDATE: So after a couple restarts seems to work, however I still don't have audio from the front panel when I plug in the headphones

Comment: I'm still having the same problem on the same mainboard. I get sound from "line out" (after installing `alsa-firmware`) but not via "headphones", even though it lists them as plugged in.